# Django-Admin override default formfield for a foreign keys field

Tags: django-admin, foreign-keys

I've read the documentation and tried to implement an override of the default formfield to display only items that belong to the current user (Publisher) in my admin. I have a SimpleSubscriber model with an object named sub_type that's a ForeignKey to the model Product. There is also a Publisher model, and both SimpleSubscriber and Product have ForeignKey objects called publisher. In my admin.py I have this:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
   if db_field.name == "sub_type":
       kwargs["queryset"] = SimpleSubscriber.objects.filter(sub_type=request.user)
   return super(SimpleSubscriberAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

In the documentation, it originally had

```
kwargs["queryset"] = SimpleSubscriber.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

But I got "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'owner' into field" so I replaced owner with sub_type, but that populated the list with subscribers.  It should be a list of sub_types (Products).

How do I get this list to show only the sub_types (Products) that belong to the current user (Publisher)?

Comment: So I am answering my own question here.
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
       if db_field.name == "sub_type":
           subtype = Product.objects.all()
           if not request.user.is_superuser:
               kwargs["queryset"] = subtype.filter(publisher=request.user)
           else:
               kwargs["queryset"] = subtype
       return super(SimpleSubscriberAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am answering my own question here.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
   if db_field.name == "sub_type":
       subtype = Product.objects.all()
       if not request.user.is_superuser:
           kwargs["queryset"] = subtype.filter(publisher=request.user)
       else:
           kwargs["queryset"] = subtype
   return super(SimpleSubscriberAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I needed to change

```
kwargs["queryset"] = SimpleSubscriber.objects.filter(sub_type=request.user)
```

to this:

```
subtype = Product.objects.all()
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        kwargs["queryset"] = subtype.filter(publisher=request.user)
    else:
        kwargs["queryset"] = subtype
```

I'm learning the hard way about filtering ForeignKey objects. Hope this saves someone a headache.